# MySQL Joins where one value can be optional

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause, option-type

### Situation

I have a database which heavily makes use of joins due to the various situations in which each entity is used. Here is a simplified diagram:

[image: MySQL Diagram]

### Goal

I would like to be able to get details of all modules and the "name" fields regardless of whether the "fk_chapter_id" within user_has_module is set or not.

- In the case where "user_has_module.fk_chapter_id" is null, the system can return details of the module and then null chapter.
- In the case where there is a user_has_module, I would like to get the status

### Issue

Whenever I perform SQL statements, I get the results only partially returned. I.E. If I have 4 module records in total, two of which where the user has an entry in "user_has_module" returns the two records in full and then 2 null records for the other modules.

### Update based on feedback, almost there

Now, the only problem is I get duplicates. Using some test data

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    chapter_id,
    chapter_name,
    module_id,
    module_name,
(null ) AS user_module_progress,
    (SELECT COUNT(fk_chapter_id) FROM module_has_chapter WHERE fk_module_id = m.module_id) AS chapter_count
FROM
    module as m
        LEFT  JOIN
    module_has_chapter as mhc ON m.module_id = mhc.fk_module_id
        LEFT JOIN
    chapter as c ON mhc.fk_chapter_id = c.chapter_id
    group by m.module_id

    UNION

SELECT DISTINCT
    chapter_id,
    chapter_name,
    module_id,
    module_name,
    user_module_progress,
(SELECT COUNT(fk_chapter_id) FROM module_has_chapter WHERE fk_module_id = m.module_id) AS chapter_count
FROM
module as m
LEFT JOIN
    user_has_module as uhm ON m.module_id = uhm.fk_module_id
LEFT JOIN
user as u ON uhm.fk_user_id = u.user_id
LEFT JOIN
    chapter as c ON uhm.fk_latest_chapter_id = c.chapter_id
WHERE u.user_id = 2
group by m.module_id;
```

[image: results]

Comment: can you elaborate please?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Full_outer_join Will return also the null values.Esentially it "gathers" everything.

Comment: If I try that, due to wanting to pull out "user_module_status", it complains about the differing number of columns

Answer (score 0):

I got there in the end but, not particularly happy about it. This works but, it's a bloody mess...Does anyone have a better solution please?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    (null) AS chapter_id,
    (null) AS chapter_name,
    module_id,
    module_name,
    (null ) AS user_module_progress,
    (SELECT COUNT(fk_chapter_id) FROM module_has_chapter WHERE fk_module_id = m.module_id) AS chapter_count
FROM
    module as m
LEFT JOIN 
     user_has_module as uhm ON m.module_id = uhm.fk_module_id
WHERE
    uhm.fk_user_id IS NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT DISTINCT
    chapter_id,
    chapter_name,
    module_id,
    module_name,
    user_module_progress,
    (SELECT COUNT(fk_chapter_id) FROM module_has_chapter WHERE fk_module_id = m.module_id) AS chapter_count
FROM
    module as m
LEFT JOIN
    user_has_module as uhm ON m.module_id = uhm.fk_module_id
INNER JOIN
    user as u ON uhm.fk_user_id = u.user_id
INNER JOIN
    chapter as c ON uhm.fk_latest_chapter_id = c.chapter_id
WHERE 
    u.user_id = 2;
```

[image: result set 2]